# How do I test the comments of the current_user in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

So I have a `User` that `has_many :comments`.

In my `Comments#Index`, I have this:

```
  def index
    @comments = current_user.comments
  end
```

Inside my `Rspec.config...` block in `rails_helper.rb` I have this:

```
  # Add Config info for Devise
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
```

My `comments_controller_spec.rb` looks like this:

```
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it "populates an array of comments that belong to a user" do
      user = create(:user)
      node = create(:node)
      comment1 = create(:comment, node: node, user: user)
      comment2 = create(:comment, node: node, user: user)
      get :index, { node_id: node  }
      expect(assigns(:comments)).to match_array([comment1, comment2])
    end
    it "renders the :index template"
  end
```

This is my `Users.rb` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    association :family_tree
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password123"
    password_confirmation "password123"
    bio { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    invitation_relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now
    gender 1
  end
end
```

This is my `Comments` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    association :node
    message { Faker::Lorem.sentence }

    factory :invalid_comment do
      message nil
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error I am getting now:

```
 Failure/Error: get :index, { node_id: node  }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you stub the sign in process in your test? [more details here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs)

Comment: I did not. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign in first:

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:node) { create(:node) }
  let(:comment1) { create(:comment, node: node, user: user) }
  let(:comment2) { create(:comment, node: node, user: user) }

  before do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end

  it "populates an array of comments that belong to a user" do
    get :index, { node_id: node }
    expect(assigns(:comments)).to match_array [comment1, comment2]
  end
end
```

You could also create a module in your `spec/support` directory with the following code:

```
module SpecAuthentication
  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in @user
  end
end
```

and include it in your `RSpec.configure` block:

```
config.include SpecAuthentication
```

Now you can call the `login_user` method in your specs:

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  let(:node) { create(:node) }
  let(:comment1) { create(:comment, node: node, user: @user) }
  let(:comment2) { create(:comment, node: node, user: @user) }

  before { login_user }

  it "populates an array of comments that belong to a user" do
    get :index, { node_id: node }
    expect(assigns(:comments)).to match_array [comment1, comment2]
  end
end
```

**Update**

Instead of including the module in the `configure` block in your `spec/rails_helper.rb` file, you could also add a `configure` block in the support file (`spec/support/devise.rb`) itself:

```
module SpecAuthorization
  ...
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SpecAuthorization
end
```

Comment: So I don't have to do anything with `current_user` in my tests, even though that is what is called in my controller? i.e. `current_user.comments`.

Comment: By the way, this makes perfect sense. I tried doing this, but I got this error: `: uninitialized constant SpecAuthentication (NameError)`. For the record, what I did was inside my `spec/rails_helper.rb` I added this line inside my config block:   `config.include SpecAuthentication`. That's where I get the error. For the module definition, I created a file called `spec/support/devise.rb` and inside that file I added that module definition. Not sure if that affects anything, but figured I would mention it.

Comment: Well, indirectly you are. In my example you sign in with the `login_user` method, which basically does: `sign_in @user`. That's the important part. Devise signs your `@user` factory in, so that `@user` object will be the currently signed in user. `current_user` is simply a helper method (provided by Devise) for your controllers to retrieve that signed in user. More info [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers).

Comment: Ahh right. That makes sense. Thanks for that explanation. See my other comment :)

Comment: @marcamillion I've updated my answer. Instead of adding the include to your `rails_helper.rb` file, you can add a `configure` block to the support file itself. Try that instead.

Comment: Ok I tried that edit, and I am now getting another error: `undefined local variable or method 'login_user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CommentsController::GETIndex:0x007f8da831ef10>`. I also started using `let` rather than regular variable assignment and now get this error also: `'let' is not available from within an example (e.g. an 'it' block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. 'before', 'let', etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a 'describe' or 'context' block).`

Comment: Ok, first of all make sure you've got something like this in your rails_helper.rb: `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`. The `let` error tells you that you've got a `let` within an `it` block instead of a `describe` or `context` block as I've shown in my example.

Comment: You are 100% right. That line in my `rails_helper` was commented out. I uncommented it, and it works perfectly. Also, the `let` error was right. I moved them out of my `it` block and now it works perfectly. Thanks much!